# Встроенные функции С++

Tags: c++

Читая одну книгу, наткнулся на встроенные функции, сложилось впечатление (благодаря описанию автора), что она гораздо быстрее обычной (вызываемой функции), но почему-то, читая чужие исходники, они встречаются там довольно редко, так в чем подвох? Напишите в общих чертах, когда следует делать функции встраиваемой, а когда нет. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дополню предыдущий ответ.

Во-первых, inline - это лишь рекомендация компилятору сделать функцию встраиваемой. Компилятор может её проигнорировать, если не согласен, что её нужно подставить. Если её нельзя подставить, например, когда используется рекурсия или указатели на эту функцию, то он её не подставит. Некоторые компиляторы поддерживают __forceinline, которую компилятор не должен игнорировать, если её можно вставить в код.

Во-вторых, все inline функции должны определяться в заголовочном файле, а не в .cpp. Кстати, даже не встраиваемые функции, находящиеся в разных cpp-файлах, могут быть встроены компоновщиком, если включена кроссмодульная оптимизация.

Также я предполагал, что компилятор может подставить только те части кода, которые могут исполняться. Если из контекста вызова функции известно, что условия всегда ложны, то код этой ветви не будет вставлен. Однако тесты показали, что компилятор может делать это и без inline.

В общем, я пришёл к выводу, что inline надо использовать в самых критичных к производительности местах, где каждый такт процессора на счету. При этом производительность надо замерять, так как не факт, что это даст прирост.

P.S:

> почему-то, читая чужие исходники, они встречаются там довольно редко

Функции не умеют читать. Это распространённая ошибка употребления деепричастных оборотов.

Comment: почему-то, читая чужие исходники, они встречаются там довольно 

      редко

Писал очень быстро, во втором окне в Dota 2 была открыта:)
P.S не стоит придираться к ошибкам, ведь смысл, который я хотел донести, вы поняли:)

Comment: "Во-вторых, все inline функции должны определяться в заголовочном файле, а не в .cpp" - то есть если функцию объявить встраиваемой в .cpp, то спецификатор Inline будет проигнорирован компилятором?

Comment: > Во-вторых, все inline функции должны определяться в заголовочном файле, а не в .cpp

Наверное это скорее рекомендация, чем правило. Или я не прав?

Comment: >то есть если функцию объявить встраиваемой в .cpp, то спецификатор Inline будет проигнорирован компилятором?

 Нет. Он подставит эту функцию только в те функции, которые находятся в этой же единице компиляции. Эта функция не будет доступна из других модулей. При попытке её вызвать компоновщик напишет, что это неразрешённый внешний символ. Правда, иногда, когда компилятор игнорирует inline, этой ошибки может и не быть.

>Наверное это скорее рекомендация, чем правило. Или я не прав?

 Именно правило. Компоновщик будет выдавать ошибку(но не всегда).

Comment: В случае gcc если функция была объявлена как inline и без static, то все равно создается отдельная копия этой функции для возможности внешнего вызова.

Comment: > Нет. Он подставит эту функцию только в те функции, которые находятся в этой же единице компиляции.

@GLmonster, так об этом я и говорю, что функция не *обязательно* должна быть в заголовочном файле, если она используется только в данном модуле.

Comment: @mikillskegg
 Это зависит от реализации компилятора, на которую полагаться не стоит. Я сужу по MSVC, который иногда создаётся копия, а иногда нет.

@insolor
 Я тебя не так понял. Это и так понятно, что заголовочные файлы тупо вставляются в код, и компилятору всё равно, где этот код находится. Но если в заголовке есть прототип функции, а определяется она только в одном модуле, то из другого модуля она не будет доступна.

Answer (score 4):

Видимо имеются ввиду `inline` функции, коли так, то их надо использовать без фанатизма. Когда компилятор встречает ключевое слово `inline` - то он тупо копирует участок кода в то место где производится вызов функции.

Преимуществами являются:

1. Экономия времени на вызов стека - в обычной функции параметры надо протолкнуть и вытолкнуть из стека
2. Отстутствие оверхеда на собсно вызов функции и возврат значения

Но при этом появляются и недостатки

1. Увеличение размера приложения - поскольку куски кода будут копироваться из одного места в другое
2. Увеличение времени компиляции (см. выше)
3. Поскольку параметры вызова встроенной функции как бы эмулируются присвоением значений локальным переменным, то количество переменных может резко вырасти (а это уже увеличение все того же стека)

В общем рецепт такой: если кусок кода маленький и мало параметров и кусок используется 2-3 раза - смело обращайте его в inline, а если нет то не мучайтесь.

Comment: Спасибо за четкий и внятный ответ.